# How to get one or none arguments with click?

Tags: python-click

Click allows for [variadic arguments](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/arguments/#variadic-arguments) like this:

```py
@click.command()
@click.argument('src', nargs=-1)
@click.argument('dst', nargs=1)
def copy(src, dst):
    """Move file SRC to DST."""
    for fn in src:
        click.echo(f"move {fn} to folder {dst}")
```

But how can I specify at most one argument? While it may be interesting to have a minimum and maximum number, I am looking for adding an optional argument.

I think `nargs=-1` and checking if `n<2` myself would work like this

```py
@click.command()
@click.argument('some_argument')
@click.argument('optional_argument', nargs=-1)
def example(some_argument, optional_argument):
    if len(option_argument) > 1:
        print("Too many arguments")
        return
    # do something with or without the optional argument
```

but the automatically generated helptext then just should `some_argument optional_argument...` and it should indicate it by `some_argument [optional_argument]`. And of course it would be nice if click could handle the check itself instead of only checking for zero or more arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may need a command option ([Click docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/options/)) here, since the argument is really optional:

```py
@click.command()
@click.argument('some_argument')
@click.option('optional_argument', default='some value')
def example(some_argument, optional_argument):
    # do something with or without the optional argument
```

Because `optional_argument` is now an option, the command can be used without providing a value for `optional_argument` or providing a single value (that will override the default value).